# Charging 18650's with 4w of power

Tags: arduino, solar-cell

I am trying to charge a 18650 battery with 4 6v 1w solar panels, My plan was to wire the panels in paralel, pass through a dc buck solar stabalizer XL6009  5v and goes to the charge controller http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-5V-18650-TP4056-Mini-USB-Lithium-Battery-1A-MicroUSB-Charger-Module-Protect-/252463499293?hash=item3ac7ff481d:g:cxYAAOSwjXRXYXEh

this then "charges the battery" and outputs to a DC Step Up Boost Power Supply 2V-5V to 5V 2A Stable Fixed Output to be used with an arduino to measure sensor data, and transit rf signals.

However For some reason the solar stabalizer does not output any signal, I believe this is due to the solar panels not providing enough current. What Can I do? This is for a Cubesat project. I was thinking of swapping the solar Stabalizer and the 2a fixed output buck but its range is 2v - 5v and the solar panels reach 7.4v in direct sun.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right.  The charge controller (TP4056 https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf) has under-voltage lockout protection.  You can measure the cell output voltage when it tries to charge and see how low it goes.  I couldn't find the UVLO threshold (Vuv) in the datasheet, but I'm guessing it's trying to draw too much current and dropping the input voltage.

What you could try is reducing the charge current.  If you can figure out where Rprog is on that board (tied to pin 2), you can see what value it is and maybe replace it with a higher value.  There is a table on p3 showing the charge current for various resistor values.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the issue id the xl6009 does not output any voltage, I will try directly powering the charge controller with the solar cells. I also noticed when  I connect the battery to the charge controller it gets very hot 60+ Cº, nothing is shorting and polarity is correct. I have some power bank charge controllers, maybe those will work but they dont have overcharge or low voltage protection.

Comment: your answer is not comprehensible

Comment: I am the op on another account.

Comment: because I logged in with different google accounts, anyways I believe the charge controller is dead as the LEDS dont turn on even when using a micro usb cable, im gonna try the spare.